# Why can't i reach data after Vue-Router params?

Tags: vuejs2, router, vuex

When i search jobs and go to the details (to another page) i can't reach any results.

i think i need vuex-store but i dont understand that property.

this is jobs detail page (and value in json's)

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      positionName: this.$route.params.positionName,
      id: this.$route.params.jobId,
      items: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$http
      .get(
        "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cqdiacEgfC?indent=2" +
          this.positionName +
          this.id
      )
      .then(function(data) {
        this.items = data.body;
      });
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="card-body"
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.id">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{positionName}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{item.companyName}}</p>
      <p class="card-text">{{item.description}}</p>
      <p class="card-text">{{item.countryName}}</p>
      <p class="card-text">{{item.cityName}}</p>
      <p class="card-text">{{item.address}}</p>
      <p class="card-text">0{{item.contactPhone.areaCode}}-{{item.contactPhone.number}}</p>
      <input type="button"
              value="Başvur!"
              class="btn btn-danger">
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is router page

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Hey from "./components/hey.vue"
import Search from "./components/search.vue"

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Search
    },
    {
      path: "/:positionName/:jobId",
      name: "JobDetail",
      component: Hey
    }
  ] 
});
```

What can i do know? Why can't i reach json value in another page after router?

Comment: What is the problem in terms of the data? In `created()` you should see valid positionName and id if you console.log().

Comment: yes i can but. i want to see job details. i mean this: http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cqdiacEgfC?indent=2

Comment: Ok, if you have confirmed the variables `positionName` and `id` are ok, the next step is to confirm `items` just after assignment from `data.body`.

Comment: **Why can't i reach json value in another page after router** - this question is not clear to me.

Comment: That url you are using is not valid. You can try it in the browser with e.g positionName 'Front End Developer' and the server responds with status code 500.